# Resize CCnode based on percentage

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

How would I resize a CCNode based on percentage? I know of `mynode.scaleY =` which works but not exaclt and I know of `mynode.scaleYInPoints` which I can't get working. Ideally I would like to set the height of the CCNode (say it is currently 100) to 70 by code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question. Scale is a percent defined where 0.0 is 0%, 1.0 is 100%, 2.0 is 200%, etc. If you want to scale your node by 70 percent you'd change it's scale to 0.7.

If you want the scale to be uniform, you'd use:

```
mynode.scale = 0.7f;
```

If you want it to be just the Y but not the X:

```
mynode.scaleY = 0.7f;
```

Edit:

If you want to set the scale to be 70 percent of what it current is, regardless of what that is, you could do:

```
mynode.scale *= 0.7f;
```